# Plane intersection in 4 dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the 4-d space ℝ4 coordinatized by (1,2,3,4). Any two of these coordinate axes spans a plane.

What is the intersection of the (1,2) plane with the (3,4) plane?

Why is the answer a point. Could someone simply explain this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Consider an analogy one dimension "down":  what is the intersection in $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ of the $ \ x-$axis with the $ \ z-$ axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as, in three dimensions, the x-axis is the set of points (x, 0, 0), so, in four dimensions, the "$x_1x_2$ plane" is the set of points $(x_1,x_2, 0, 0)$ and the "$x_3x_4$ plane" is the set of points $(0, 0,x_3, x_4)$.

That is, every point in the "$x_1x_2$ plane" must have $x_3= x_4= 0$ and every point in the "$x_3x_4$ plane" must have $x_1= x_2= 0$.

A point in their intersection is in both planes so must have $x_1= x_2= x_3= x_4= 0$.  The only point satisfying that is the origin, (0, 0, 0,0).